# vb.net combobox different style to C# combobox

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, combobox

When creating a combobox on the design surface of a VB.NET app in VS 2008 it is white and when creating it in C# it is gray.

How do I create a combobox in C# that looks just like the VB.NET one?  (Style wise)

[alt text http://www.tonysoenen.com/images/combos.jpg](http://www.tonysoenen.com/images/combos.jpg)

Comment: I can't recreate this. These are completely 'clean' comboboxes just dragged from Toolbox to the form?

Comment: yes, just cleanly dragged from toolbox.  In my VS one is white where you'd type the text in VB.NET and in C# it is gray

Comment: not sure what you mean by that?

Comment: If it is gray it may be a sign that the control has been disabled.  when you run the app, can you still type in it while it is gray?

Comment: I found what the problem is, the DropDownStyle property was set to DropDownList...  :) Mystery solved! Thanks for the help

Comment: That's not cleanly dragged from the toolbox then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The different styles are because of the drop-down style of these controls. To get the same style as for VB.NET, you can simply change the drop-down style property to "dropDown" for the ComboBox in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Have you been using any custom controls? If you mouse over the Toolbox entry before you drag the control to the form, does the tooltip in both cases say "Version 2.0.0.0 from Microsoft Corporation .NET component"?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the all the properties of both forms and both comboboxes to make sure they are the same. For example, it appears that your C# form has a different background color than the VB form.